# SQL Query SUM issue

Tags: sql, sum

I am writing a SQL query where i want to list down and calculate some data every thing looks to work fine but the only problem I am having is when i SUM values in a given column the final result is a overall total but i want this total only to be for a month of October.

The scenario is as followed i need to calculate a total amount of deposits made by costomers over the month of October with other information that works well its only the sum issue.

SQL:

```
SELECT customers.id                                      AS 'Customer ID', 
       customers.firstname                               AS 
       'Customer First Name', 
       customers.lastname                                AS 'Customer Last Name' 
       , 
       users.firstname                                   AS 
       'Employee First Name', 
       users.lastname                                    AS 'Employee Last Name' 
       , 
       positions.currency                                AS 'Currency', 
       Sum(customer_deposits.amount)                     AS 'Total Deposits', 
       Sum(positions.status)                             AS 'Total Bets', 
       Sum(customer_total_statistics.totalbonusdeposits) AS 'Total Bonuses', 
       positions.date                                    AS 'Date' 
FROM   customers 
       LEFT JOIN customer_deposits 
              ON customers.id = customer_deposits.customerid 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON customers.employeeinchargeid = users.id 
       LEFT JOIN positions 
              ON customers.id = positions.customerid 
       LEFT JOIN customer_total_statistics 
              ON customers.id = customer_total_statistics.customerid 
WHERE  customer_deposits.status = 'approved' 
       AND positions.status = 'won' 
       AND positions.date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-01' 
       AND customers.isdemo = '0' 
GROUP  BY customers.id 
ORDER  BY customers.id
```

Comment: Please learn to properly format your questions. You posted over 50 posts by now. Use the `{}` button to format code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't filter your customer_deposits at all, so the sum over customer_deposits.amount will of course give you the sum of all the deposits. You'll have to add another where to filter customer_deposits by date as well, not just positions.

Comment: What do u mean am not filtering my customer_deposits..? could you please extend your answer. thx

Comment: You're filtering by positions.date. However, you join customer_deposits table, and the only way the two are related, is that you don't get customers, which had nothing in positions during that date. However, you always get all the records in customer_deposits for those customers. If it's possible, I'd add a new where filter, `and customer_deposits.date between '2013-10-01' and '2013-11-01'`. In other words, unless you're joining positions directly, you're always getting all the data of the customers. You have to filter each table separately in that case.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have multiple 1-n relationships so your joins are creating cartesian products. So if you had a customer with 2 deposits and 2 positions:

```
Positions                       customer_deposits

CustomerID | Amount             CustomerID | Amount         
1          |  10                    1      |  30
1          |  20                    1      |  40
```

When you do this join:

```
SELECT  c.ID, cd.Amount AS DepositAmount, p.Amount AS PositionAmount
FROM    Customers c
        INNER JOIN customer_deposits cd
            ON c.ID = cd.CustomerID
        INNER JOIN Positions p
            ON c.ID = p.CustomerID
```

You end up with 4 rows with all combinations of deposit amount and position amount:

```
ID  DepositAmount PositionAmount
1       10              30
1       10              40
1       20              30
1       20              40
```

So if you sum this up you end up with incorrect sums because rows are duplicated. You need to move your SUMs to subqueries:

```
SELECT customers.id             AS 'Customer ID', 
       customers.firstname      AS 'Customer First Name', 
       customers.lastname       AS 'Customer Last Name',
       users.firstname          AS 'Employee First Name', 
       users.lastname           AS 'Employee Last Name',
       positions.currency       AS 'Currency', 
       cd.amount                AS 'Total Deposits', 
       P.status                 AS 'Total Bets', 
       cs.totalbonusdeposits    AS 'Total Bonuses', 
       positions.date           AS 'Date' 
FROM   customers 
       INNER JOIN 
       (    SELECT  CustomerID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
            FROM    customer_deposits 
            WHERE   customer_deposits.status = 'approved' 
            GROUP BY CustomerID
        ) cd
              ON customers.id = cd.customerid 
       LEFT JOIN users 
              ON customers.employeeinchargeid = users.id 
       INNER JOIN 
       (    SELECT  CustomerID, Date, SUM(Status) AS Status
            FROM    positions 
            WHERE   positions.status = 'won' 
            AND     positions.date BETWEEN '2013-10-01' AND '2013-11-01' 
            GROUP BY CustomerID, Date
        ) P
            ON customers.id = positions.customerid 
       LEFT JOIN 
       (    SELECT  CustomerID, SUM(totalbonusdeposits) AS totalbonusdeposits
            FROM    customer_total_statistics 
            GROUP BY CustomerID
        ) cs
            ON customers.id = customer_total_statistics.customerid 
WHERE   customers.isdemo = '0';
```

Note, you have used fields in the where clause for left joined tables which effectively turns them into an inner join, e.g.

```
positions.status = 'won'
```

If there is no match in positions, the status will be `NULL`, and `NULL = 'won'` evaluates to NULL (not true) so it will exclude all rows where there is no match in `position`. As such I have changed your LEFT JOIN's to INNER.